# Pass current GET Variables with href

Tags: php, html, get

Let's say I am on `www.example.com/?par1=test` and I have a Link like: `<a href="/subpage">Link text</a>`.

How to pass the GET Variable to the subpage, without reading every Parameter e.G. `$_GET["par1"]` and pass it to the Link by hand.

Comment: DO you want to replace `/subpage` with the `$_GET` variable?

Comment: No I want to add my GET Variables like `/subpage/?par1=test`

Comment: How exactly do you want to retrieve information without reading it? That's kinda like trying to drive a car without having access to a car.

Comment: @BryanAbrams See the answers. There is it ;)

Comment: Just so you know $_GET is an array, you're still reading in $_GET["par1"]. The difference between the answer and using a string literal is the answer is a dynamic solution that allow for any parameters whereas yours is hard coded and less flexible.

Comment: @BryanAbrams That's the reason why I am asking this Question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to pass *all* get variables to next page just do next thing:

```
$href = '/somepage/';
if ($_GET) {
    $href .= strpos($href, '?') === false ? '?' : '&';
    $href .= http_build_query($_GET);
}
```

Then echo this href

```
<a href="<?=$href;?>">my link</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for this elegant solution. It works :). Altough the other solutions where good as well

Answer (score 4):

$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] contains the data that you are looking for.

[PHP: $_SERVER - Manual](https://www.php.net/reserved.variables.server.php)

Answer (score 1):

Use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php). It returns an array like:

```
$out = parse_url('www.example.com/?par1=test');
var_dump($out);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
[path] => www.example.com/
[query] => par1=test
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href='www.example.com.br?pas1=<?php echo $variavel  ?>'>Link</a>;
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I don't want to do

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function to aid your link generation.

Obviously this is a simple example but you could easily extend it.

```
    function getLink($url, array $params = array())
    {
        if (empty($params)) return $url;

        $url .= '?';
        foreach($params as $param => $value) {
            $url .= $param .'='. $value;
        }
        return $url;
    }

    $params = array(
        'test' => 1,
        'foo' => 'hello',
        'bar' => 'test',
    );
    echo getLink('my/target/page.php', $params);
```

The `$params` array could be substituted for the super-global `$_GET` to make life easier!

Comment: Url can already contain '?'.
Params have to be urlencoded, http_build_query does it. Do not use foreach loop for that.

Answer (score 0):

As with many problems, there are many solutions!

The simplest is probably just to append your URL with the contents of `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`, e.g.:

```
<a href="/somefile?<?php echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ?>">somefile</a>
```

But this does rely on your webserver correctly passing through the correct parameters I believe. Apache should do this out of the box with mod_php, but FastCGI based PHP may need some additional config.

Take a look at [the documentation for the `$_SERVER` variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Answer (score 0):

this is a example of how to do this :

```
<?php
echo print_r($_GET);
echo "<br>";
echo "www.mysite.com/index.php?".http_build_query($_GET);
?>
```

will print : (if url is : http://www.mysite.com/index.php?this=1&that=2 )

Array ( [this] => 1 [that] => 2 ) 1

www.mysite.com/index.php?this=1&that=2